# Spark: copying an aggregated column of another table - withColumn

Tags: apache-spark

say I have two datasets which have the following columns:

root (as table)

```
 |-- brand: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- type: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- sum(brand): long (nullable = true)
```

root (as table2)

```
 |-- brand: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- type: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- sum(type): long (nullable = true)
```

say I want to add the column of `table2` called `sum(type)` to `table`. I have tried this but it does not work for some reason:

`table = table.withColumn("last", table2.col("sum(type)"));`

how can I approach this?

Comment: you need to perform to copy one column to another table. check any join.try to read the documentation before writing into stack overflow

Comment: withColumn does not allow to process another datafram column. You simple need to join like below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 val table3  = table.alias("tab").join(table2.alias("tab2"),"brand").select("tab.*","tab2.sum(type)".alias("last"))
```